# Ho to use preg_match_all to find a string that has specific beging and specific end?-PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am using this regex on css file to find all font-face fonts and to add missing full path to the font string.

```
    if(preg_match_all("/(url\('(.*?)'\))/s", $readcssfile, $fontstrings)){

        $fontstrings[1] = str_replace("('", "('newpath/", $fontstrings[1]);

        print_r($fontstrings[1]);
    }
```

this is the return  .

```
Array
(
    [0] => url('newpath/../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot')
    [1] => url('newpath/../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix')
    [2] => url('newpath/../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff')
    [3] => url('newpath/../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf')
    [4] => url('newpath/../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular')
    [5] => url('newpath/PTN77F-webfont.eot')
    [6] => url('newpath/PTN77F-webfont.eot?#iefix')
    [7] => url('newpath/PTN77F-webfont.woff')
    [8] => url('newpath/PTN77F-webfont.ttf')
    [9] => url('newpath/PTN77F-webfont.svg#PTSansNarrowBold')
)
```

What I am actually looking for are those that have no relative path

```
url('PTN77F ...
```

But as you can see I found all fonts. 
I must be very specific so I would not make any mistakes , I need to match all

```
eot|#iefix|woff|ttf|svg,
```

that do not have relative paths like , ../ or ..anything

and change their path to new path.

The thing is as soon as I add something like this in regex

```
preg_match_all("/(url\('(.*?).eot'\))/s", $readcssfile, $fontstrings)
```

I end up with array that has complete stylesheet in it.

**I cannot search by actual font name since I will never know what it will be.**

So how to I match only the ones that dont have relative path 
and how to find fonts with specific extension?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First assert that there is no relative path by making sure no `../` exists on the line:

```
(?!.*\.\.\/)
```

Then modify the above expression to grab the actual URL into a capture group:

```
^(?!.*\.\.\/)url\('?(.*?)'?\)$
```

And then for each match there will be an array element `[1]` with the captured URL and `[0]` will be the full match.

Note: this should be done so that `^` / `$` match *per line*, so ensure the `m` flag is *not* set.

Answer (score 0):

It was much easier than I thought by referencing this here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/594423

I end up matching  only the ones that have nothing before  ('

and replacing them

```
preg_replace("/(url\('(?!\.)(?!\/))/s","url('newpath/", $readcssfile);
```

it is kinda what tenub referenced in the fist line